# Reactive Forms typescript CKEDITOR CustomValueModule

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, ckeditor, reactive

I am trying to convert this CustomValueModule into a CKEDITOR control but I am getting a error that the tag is not support. The Component template is a div tag so I am not sure why I am getting this error.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5kvfys

Error

```
EXCEPTION: The specified element mode is not supported on element: "editor".
```

view

```
<Editor 
        [formControl]="controlGroup.controls.value" >
</Editor>
```

Component

```
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'Editor',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => Editor),
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    template: `<div [attr.id]="editorId" contenteditable="true"
                style="width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden"
                class="form-control sentence-part-values-inline sentence-part-values-inline-textbox-number">
                </div>`,
})
export class Editor implements ControlValueAccessor {
    constructor() { }

    onChange: any = () => { }
    onTouch: any = () => { }
    val = ""

    set value(val) {
        if (val !== undefined && this.val !== val) {
            this.val = val
            this.onChange(val)
            this.onTouch(val)
        }

    }

    writeValue(value: any) {
        this.value = value
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChange = fn
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
        this.onTouch = fn
    }
}
```

Component

ngAfterViewInit() {

```
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    (<any>window).CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false;
    if (!(<any>window).CKEDITOR.instances[this.editorId]) {
```

updated

```
initControlGroup(fb: FormBuilder) : FormGroup {
    return fb.group({
        "value": [""]            
    });
}

public form: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    editorValue: ["",Validators.required]
});
```

Error when I remove the public form: FormGroup and just have the initControlGroup

```
EXCEPTION: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:


    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });
```

Comment: your blitz is broken... ckeditor probably leaves some extraneous tags in it's value. like a br or an empty div or soemthing.  have you inspected the value in like valueChanges to see what it actually is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you trying to achieve here is creating editor that you could bind it's value to reactive-forms I did that exactly.

*I found some issues with your code. So, in order to help, I re-wrote the code with comments so you could benefit from it.*

**Full working code:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wv9vdi

Comment: thanks for the sample can I just use change event to remove the validating?

Comment: @Jefferson you are welcome sorry didn't get your question  ?

Comment: can I use Renderer and not Renderer2? I get an error about setProperty does not exit ?

Comment: Yes it must work since `Renderer` is the previous version from `Renderer2`.. but what angular version you currently using so that you still have `Renderer` ?

Comment: I think the in `Renderer` you must use the following `this.renderer.setElementAttribute(div, "textContent", this._value);`  this must give you same result sorry can't test angular 9 doesn't have Renderer under `@angular/core;`

Comment: @angular-devkit/architect    0.8.1
@angular-devkit/core         0.8.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.1
@schematics/angular          0.8.1
@schematics/update           0.8.1
rxjs                         6.2.2
typescript                   2.9.2

Comment: please check "@angular/core": "^8.2.14", that where `Renderer` Found ... I think updating @angular/cli will let you use Renderer2

Comment: Should I have both initControlGroup and this.formBuilder.group

Comment: this.formBuilder.group is enough for building reactive forms ... please sure the exact error I maybe be able to help more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214348/discussion-between-hussein-akar-and-jefferson).

Comment: stackblitz link is broken